# Solute and Solvent classification in a Solution

Tags: solutions

When I look up the definition of solute and solvent, the definition by the Oxford English Dictionary is

```
solute

/ˈsɒljuːt,sɒˈljuːt/

noun

the ***minor*** component in a solution, dissolved in the solvent.
```

What does minor imply here? Does it classify them as solute and solvent as per mass/volume comparison? Or does it refer to their concentration?

Comment: These general definitions focus rather on usual cases and have troubles with extremes which put them in a question.

Comment: Not that it clarifies much as compared to the above dictionary but here it is https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/S05746 which becomes a bit clearer togheter with https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/S05746. Also upvoted the answer by P. M. below.

Comment: @Alchimista You posted the same link twice.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン thanks. The first link above should have been https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/S05744.